# SLD PointSymbolizer remove offset in legend?

Tags: geoserver, sld

I'm trying to style a point layer with map markers using GeoServer, so that each marker points to the geometry it represents. The markers are a variation of the droplet-type icon that has become common place in web-based mapping, e.g. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Map_marker.svg

As far as I can tell the options are either:

- Use `<se:Displacement>` to move the SVG marker. This is how the SLD produced by QGIS handles things, however by displacing the marker it disappears in the `GetLegendGraphic` response.
- Use an `offset` transformation (in map coordinates) on the point. This doesn't work to reliably position the marker.
- Uploading a static legend image to GeoServer. This has the side-effect that the `width` and `height` parameters in the `GetLegendGraphic` resize the entire image, and not individual symbols.
- Using an SVG marker image with extra padding, so that the pointy end of the marker is in the symbol's center. This results in the marker and its label not being aligned in the `GetLegendGraphic`

It feels like I'm overlooking something somewhere. How can I offset a marker from its point but keep it visible in the legend?

Answer (score 2):

The legend builder just paints a mini-map using the same code as the map rendering, thus, respects the same offsets. One needs to write code to remove the offsets from the style before painting is called.

Pull requests to improve the legend building code are welcomed, see https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

If you decide to work on this, get on the geoserver-devel list and ask for directions, core devs are likely happy to give you some hints.